# SSRS Parameter Selection disappear

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Hoping someone can help. I am very confused. I have a client working on SSRS (SQL Server 2014). We have reports running and they ran fine in the past. Since about a week ago when selecting a specific parameter and clicking on view report, the selection in the parameter field reverts to nothing. It seems to happen almost immediately without querying the data.

There are multiple reports with the same parameter and they have the same issue, letting me to believe it is a data issue, but I can't see anything that might be wrong in the data.

If you have any advice I would highly appreciate it.

The DataSet for Sites:

```
  Select SiteName from Sites
    Order by SiteName
```

Its a very basic query. Nothing strange...

[image]

[image]

Comment: is the site parameter dependent on the dates?

Comment: No, I actually don't even past it to the stored proc. Just use it to filter the Tablix on the report.

Comment: Is there a dataset query supplying data to the Site parameter? If so please edit the question and show the query.

Comment: Updated the question with the DataSet query. It is very Basic, I initially thought that there might be leading / trailing spaces, which might cause the selection not to recognize the dataset values, but this is also not the case.

Comment: Two silly questions - I assume you have run the query and seen that it returns results? And have you double checked that the query for the param uses the same data source, not a second one where the database changed?

Comment: yes query runs perfectly in SQL. You made me look with the data source, but they are the same as well.

Comment: what happens if you remove the parameter and then add it back in. Set the default values to sitename from your sites query?

Comment: @Harry its runs fine then, also very strange that I just noticed is that some sites works perfectly, so it looks like only certain sites does this.

Comment: I have removed the parameter and added it, it made no difference.

Comment: Does it make any difference If you set the datasource property to "use single transaction when processing the query"? When the parameter value disappears, are you able to reselect them or do they not appear at all?

Comment: No difference if I set it to "single select". I can reselect, but as soon as I click view report the selection is gone.

Comment: I think we are clutching at straws here but... Can you try re-ordering the parameters so the dates are last. You will need to do this directly in the .RDL file (re-ordering in the designer will not help), so make a backup. If you are using Visual Studio you can just right-click the file in the solution explorer and click "View Code"